# Move position of Label in iOS 8

Tags: ios, constraints

I´m trying to move the position of a Label but it does not work.

What i´ve done so far is to add a Label zu my view, add the constraints for initial position.

within viewDidLoad() i now want to move the label to another position.

The basic idea is to have three labels and according to some states, change the order of the labels.

i tried this within viewDidLoad():

```
var point1 = beacon1Label.center as CGPoint
var point2 = beacon2Label.center as CGPoint
var point3 = beacon3Label.center as CGPoint

beacon3Label.center = point1
beacon1Label.center = point2
```

but the position does not change. Do i have to disable the constraints to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using constraints, rather than adjust the center, you should adjust the constraint instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to *disable* the constraints, but you are absolutely right that the constraints are involved. Constraints position things. And they get the final say, whenever layout happens. Therefore, your attempt to change the `center` fails - it does work, but before you get to see anything, layout does happen, and the constraints are obeyed.

You must work *with* your constraints, not *against* them. Your first goal should be to get the constraints right in the first place! The fact that you are trying to change the position of things right there in `viewDidLoad` is a "bad smell"; it implies that your constraints are wrong.

But if you can't do that, and for some reason you must reposition something in code, then your code must change the *constraints*, not the `center` or `frame` of the view.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a good pattern how to deal with my problem? It sounds that it is not a good coding style what i´m trying to do. Any better idea?

Comment: I don't know what your problem _is_. Why are you rearranging the labels at `viewDidLoad` time? It doesn't make sense to me. But if you must do that, just do what I said: change the constraints. It is not difficult.

Comment: move them in vewDidLoad is only for testing, of course i will move them within other events later.

Comment: @solick That's fine. Perhaps you could have made that clear in your original question! In any case, my answer is still the same. To move views that are positioned by constraints, change the constraints. This is standard procedure and is not at all difficult. You can change the `constant` of particular constraints, or you can swap entire constraints in and out. This is the third time I've told you this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the center like this, you have to remove the constraints. This approach will not work with constraints. If you want to use the same approach with constraints you should do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: My problem is, that i want to move than after recalculation of some values. They shall be sorted according to internal values.